# TypeError when opening a file in python

Tags: python, file, typeerror

I wanted to read a file, but it gave me an error. Changing from  `"r"` to `"rt"` still gives the error. If i change the `"r"` to `1`, it gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'readlines'`

This is the code:

```py
from os import *
system("clear")
file = open("data.txt", "r")
text = file.readlines()
file.close()
print(text)
```

I thought it would output the contents of the file, but instead it got me an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/whitespace/coding/python/scripts/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    file = open("data.txt", "r")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: What's the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Do you have `from os import *` at the top of this file? You appear to be shadowing the build-in `open` with `os.open`, and they behave differently. `os.open` takes integer flags instead of a string for its second argument.

Comment: Ya, you're using `os.open` for some reason instead of the normal built-in. Double check your imports, and avoid doing `... import *` (assuming that's what's causing the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing os using `from os import *` imports the `open` method from the is module, which functions differently. Then calling open, it defaults to the os open method instead of the built-in open method.

This should work:

```py
from os import system
system("clear")
file = open("data.txt", "r")
text = file.readlines()
file.close()
print(text)
```